# Window management - opening, closing & re-opening non-modal forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, non-modal

In pseudocode, this is what I am trying to do from a main window, with many non-modal sub-windows that can be opened and closed independently of the main window.
(Think "preferences" or "find")

On pressing "OPEN WINDOW"
STEP 1: If window does not exist, create it.
STEP 2: Window now exists, so bring it to the front & make it visible.
(Step 2 is NB in case OPEN WINDOW is pressed while window is already open - I don't want multiple instances of it, just bring it to the front.)

On pressing "CLOSE WINDOW"
STEP 3: Close the window
ALT STEP 3: Hide the window

This is the code I have tried. I got as far as being able to open the window, and bring it to the front if OPEN WINDOW is pressed again while the window is open. However, once I close the window, I CANNOT get it to open a second time. I get an error stating that Window.Show() cannot be used once the window is closed.

```
public static void OpenWindowOnce(Window windowToOpen)
    {
        foreach (Window n in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            //Checks if the window is already open, and brings it to the front if it is
            if (n.GetType() == windowToOpen.GetType())
                {}                    
            else
                {  windowToOpen.Show(); }
        }

        windowToOpen.Activate();
    }
```

Where am I going wrong in my code/logic? Thank you, I am pretty new to coding and have spent weeks trying to get this right.

Comment: Try User Controls for Non Modal forms and host them in a panel. That would be easier and will look more elegant

Comment: Have you tried disposing the form once you close it?

Comment: That's because you must handle "`Closed`" event. Instead of using `Application.Current.Windows`, use your owned created array list of forms. and handle "`Closed`" event. When the window is being closed, remove it from you array.

Comment: You cannot use a `Window` that has been closed because its resources are disposed at that time. The solution is to simply create a new `Window` each time that you want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `Window` that has been closed because its resources are disposed at that time. The solution is to simply create a new `Window` each time that you want to display it.

I can see that you are passing in a `Window` object and then trying to find the particular type of `Window`... in this case, you can use reflection to instantiate your `Window`s from their `Type`. In particular, please see the [`Activator.CreateInstance` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. You could use it something like this:

```
public static void OpenWindowOnce(Window windowToOpen)
{
    foreach (Window n in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        //Checks if the window is already open, and brings it to the front if it is
        if (n.GetType() == windowToOpen.GetType()) { ... }
        else
        {
            windowToOpen = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourWindow)) as YourWindow;
            windowToOpen.Show(); 
        }
    }
    windowToOpen.Activate();
}
```